Reading values from a key value based file and passing these values to azure devops template
Recently I am working on a pipeline where in one stage I am reading values from a key value based file and setting them using:
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$key;isOutput=true]$value"

In my future job for instance if I read these values I am able to view them but when I am trying to pass these values to my template under parameters these are not getting pass and in the template execution I see on the console command not found.
I have read and found many solution which are referring to passing parameters like ${{parameters.varname }} but I don't find an example related to passing dynamic variables to the template.
My main pipeline code is as below
trigger:
  branches:
    exclude:
      - '*'

pr:
  branches:
    exclude:
      - '*'

parameters:
  - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    displayName: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    type: string
  - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    displayName: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    type: string
  - name: AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
    displayName: AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
    type: string

variables:
  branchName: "$(Build.SourceBranchName)"
  
stages:
  - stage: CheckBranch
    displayName: "Check Branch"
    jobs:
      - job: IdentifyBranch
        displayName: "Identify Branch Job"
        pool:
          vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
        steps:
          - checkout: self
          - task: CmdLine@2
            name: VerifyBranchName
            displayName: "Identify branch if it is master or other feature/ release/ hotfix/*"
            inputs:
              script: |
                echo "Branch name is: $(Build.SourceBranchName)"
                if [ "$(Build.SourceBranchName)" = "master" ] || [[ "$(Build.SourceBranchName)" == hotfix/* ]]; then
                  echo "This is a production deployment (master branch)"
                  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isProduction;isOutput=true]true"
                  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isValidBranch;isOutput=true]true"
                elif [ "$(Build.SourceBranchName)" = "develop" ]; then
                  echo "This is a non-production deployment (develop branch)"
                  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isProduction;isOutput=true]false"
                  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isValidBranch;isOutput=true]true"
                else
                  echo "This branch is not valid for deployment, $(Build.SourceBranchName)"
                  exit 0
                fi

  - stage: LoadEnvironment
    displayName: "Load Environment Variables"
    dependsOn: CheckBranch
    jobs:
      - job: LoadEnvVariables
        displayName: "Load Environment Variables Job"
        pool:
          vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
        variables:
          isProduction: $[ stageDependencies.CheckBranch.IdentifyBranch.outputs['VerifyBranchName.isProduction'] ]
          isValidBranch: $[ stageDependencies.CheckBranch.IdentifyBranch.outputs['VerifyBranchName.isValidBranch'] ]
        steps:
          - task: CmdLine@2
            name: LoadEnvironmentValues
            displayName: "Loading values based on branch type"
            inputs:
              script: |
                echo "Checking if it's a production branch..."
                if [ "$(isProduction)" = "true" ]; then
                  echo "Production branch detected"
                fi

                echo "Checking if the branch is valid..."
                if [ "$(isValidBranch)" = "true" ]; then
                  echo "Valid branch detected: $(isValidBranch)"
                else
                  echo "This is not a valid branch, terminating flow."
                  exit 1
                fi

                cd aws/greengrass/
                if [ "$(isProduction)" = "true" ]; then
                  echo "Loading production environment variables"
                  envFile="production.env"
                else
                  echo "Loading non-production environment variables"
                  envFile="non-production.env"
                fi
      
                # Load environment variables and dynamically create parameters
                while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
                  if [[ ! -z "$line" && "$line" != \#* ]]; then
                    key=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 1)
                    value=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 2-)

                    echo "Setting parameter $key=$value"
                    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$key;isOutput=true]$value"
                  fi
                done < "$envFile"
          - script: |
              echo "stageDeps - $(stageDeps)"
              echo "COMPONENT_VERSION - $(LoadEnvironmentValues.COMPONENT_VERSION)"
              echo "GW_VERSION is $(LoadEnvironmentValues.GW_VERSION)"
              echo "SSO_ACCOUNT_ID - $(LoadEnvironmentValues.SSO_ACCOUNT_ID)"
              echo "AWS_REGION - $(LoadEnvironmentValues.AWS_REGION)"
              echo "GG_BUCKET_NAME - $(LoadEnvironmentValues.GG_BUCKET_NAME)"
              echo "KINESIS_STREAM - $(LoadEnvironmentValues.KINESIS_STREAM)"
              echo "CORE_DEVICE - $(LoadEnvironmentValues.CORE_DEVICE)"
            displayName: Check output variables

  - template: greengrass-component-deployment-templ.yml
    parameters:
      COMPONENT_VERSION: $[ dependencies.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.COMPONENT_VERSION'] ]
      GW_VERSION: $[ dependencies.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.GW_VERSION'] ]
      SSO_ACCOUNT_ID: $[ dependencies.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.SSO_ACCOUNT_ID'] ]
      AWS_REGION: $[ dependencies.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.AWS_REGION'] ]
      GG_BUCKET_NAME: $[ dependencies.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.GG_BUCKET_NAME'] ]
      KINESIS_STREAM: $[ dependencies.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.KINESIS_STREAM'] ]
      CORE_DEVICE: $[ dependencies.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.CORE_DEVICE'] ]

      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ parameters.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ parameters.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: ${{ parameters.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN }}

NOTE: Update template code:
parameters:
- name: COMPONENT_VERSION
  default: ''
- name: GW_VERSION
  default: ''
- name: SSO_ACCOUNT_ID
  default: ''
- name: AWS_REGION
  default: ''
- name: GG_BUCKET_NAME
  default: ''
- name: KINESIS_STREAM
  default: ''
- name: CORE_DEVICE
  default: ''

- name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  default: ''
- name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  default: ''
- name: AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
  default: ''


stages:
  - stage: CreateOrUpdateComponent
    dependsOn: LoadEnvironment
    variables: 
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{parameters.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{parameters.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}
      AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: ${{parameters.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}}
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ${{parameters.AWS_REGION}}
    displayName: 'Flow for Greengrass Component Creation and Update'
    jobs:
      - job: greengrass_component_deployment
        dependsOn: LoadEnvVariables
        variables:
          jobDeps: $[convertToJson(dependencies)]
          COMPONENT_VERSION: ${{ parameters.COMPONENT_VERSION }}
          GW_VERSION: ${{ parameters.GW_VERSION }}
          SSO_ACCOUNT_ID: ${{ parameters.SSO_ACCOUNT_ID }}
          AWS_REGION: ${{ parameters.AWS_REGION }}
          GG_BUCKET_NAME: ${{ parameters.GG_BUCKET_NAME }}
          KINESIS_STREAM: ${{ parameters.KINESIS_STREAM }}
          CORE_DEVICE: ${{ parameters.CORE_DEVICE }}
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo "deps - $(jobDeps)"
              echo "COMPONENT_VERSION - $(COMPONENT_VERSION)"
              echo "GW_VERSION is $(GW_VERSION)"
              echo "SSO_ACCOUNT_ID - $(SSO_ACCOUNT_ID)"
              echo "AWS_REGION - $(AWS_REGION)"
              echo "GG_BUCKET_NAME - $(GG_BUCKET_NAME)"
              echo "KINESIS_STREAM - $(KINESIS_STREAM)"
              echo "CORE_DEVICE - $(CORE_DEVICE)"
    # Job 1: Verify if the folder for greengrass component exist in S3 bucket
      - job: VerifyS3FolderForGGComponent
        displayName: 'Verify Folder for Greengrass Component'
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
        - script: |
              echo "AWS_REGIN: ${{parameters.AWS_REGION}}"
              echo "DevIoTDevice1 ${{parameters.CORE_DEVICE}}"
              echo "sso account id : ${{parameters.SSO_ACCOUNT_ID}}"
        # Task 1: Verify if the folder for greengrass component exists
        - task: CmdLine@2
          displayName: 'Verify if Greengrass Folder Exists'
          inputs:
            script: |  
              echo "Verifying if component folder exists in s3 Bucket..."
              COMPONENT_FOLDER_EXISTS=$(aws s3api list-objects --bucket "${{ parameters.GG_BUCKET_NAME }}" --query 'Contents[].Key' --output text | grep -c "artifacts/com.test.dl.gs/${{ parameters.COMPONENT_VERSION }}") || echo "0"
              echo "Component Exists: $COMPONENT_FOLDER_EXISTS"
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=COMPONENT_FOLDER_EXISTS]$COMPONENT_FOLDER_EXISTS"
              echo "Verify s3 bucket component folder response : $COMPONENT_FOLDER_EXISTS"
        - task: CmdLine@2
          displayName: "When s3 bucket does not exist"
          condition: eq(variables['COMPONENT_FOLDER_EXISTS'], '0')
          inputs:
            script: |
              pwd
              ls -lrtha
              cd ./aws/greengrass
              ls -ltrh ./artifacts/com.test.dl.gs/${{ parameters.COMPONENT_VERSION }}
              echo "Creating the Artifact dir for the component ${{ parameters.GG_BUCKET_NAME }} "
              #Pushing data to the s3 bucket 
              aws s3 sync ./artifacts/com.test.dl.gs/${{ parameters.COMPONENT_VERSION }} s3://${{ parameters.GG_BUCKET_NAME }}/artifacts/com.test.dl.gs/${{ parameters.COMPONENT_VERSION }}/
        - task: CmdLine@2
          displayName: "If component directory already exists..."
          condition: ne(variables['COMPONENT_FOLDER_EXISTS'], '0')
          inputs:
            script: |
              echo "Folder "artifacts/com.test.dl.gs/${{ parameters.COMPONENT_VERSION }}" already exists in bucket ${{ parameters.GG_BUCKET_NAME }}"

- template: greengrass-component-deployment-templ.yml
parameters:
  COMPONENT_VERSION: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.COMPONENT_VERSION'] ]
  GW_VERSION: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.GW_VERSION'] ]
  SSO_ACCOUNT_ID: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.SSO_ACCOUNT_ID'] ]
  AWS_REGION: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.AWS_REGION'] ]
  GG_BUCKET_NAME: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.GG_BUCKET_NAME'] ]
  KINESIS_STREAM: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.KINESIS_STREAM'] ]
  CORE_DEVICE: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.CORE_DEVICE'] ]

  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ parameters.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ parameters.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
  AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: ${{ parameters.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN }}


Hello, I see the issue here is that, your template will be evaluated at compile time, i.e. when the task variable is not yet set. Where as setting of task variable happens at runtime. Maybe you can look at other ways ? Use a file to store them and artifact utilization in your template ?

Thanks for the clarification I managed to pass these variables by adding a new stage with the name deploy and inside this I first load these values in variables and then at the same job call my template, I can see values in template now but problem is I have to change my template structure move jobs to task etc which I want to avoid for some reason

One more reason is I am calling aws services so at each task level I need to pass these variables which is another reason I don’t want to restructure

Once they are stage level variables, and if your template resides in the same stage, you can directly access them via environment.

Update
Based on the further discussions, below are the sample main pipeline YAML definition and template for your reference. Please modify the indentation for - template: greengrass-component-deployment-templ.yml in MainPipelineDefinition.yml the same as that of - stage: LoadEnvironment to help understand that you would prefer to output variables across stages rather than across jobs.
Unlike parameters (such as ${{parameters.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}) defined in MainPipelineDefinition.yml that were processed at compile time before pipeline runtime, the template parameters like the ${{parameters.AWS_REGION}} defined in greengrass-component-deployment-templ.yml could only dynamically retrieve their values at pipeline runtime. Therefore, the script using compile time expression like echo "AWS_REGIN: ${{parameters.AWS_REGION}}" would not work as expected. We could declare new variables in downstream stage like AWS_REGION: ${{ parameters.AWS_REGION }} and use its macro syntax instead like echo "AWS_REGION - $(AWS_REGION)". For further reference, please go through the document to Understand variable syntax.
MainPipelineDefinition.yml
trigger: none

parameters:
- name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
  default: xxx
- name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  default: yyy
- name: AWS_SESSION_TOKEN 
  default: zzz

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: CheckBranch
  jobs:
  - job: IdentifyBranch
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isProduction;isOutput=true]true"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isValidBranch;isOutput=true]true"
      name: VerifyBranchName

- stage: LoadEnvironment
  displayName: "Load Environment Variables"
  dependsOn: CheckBranch
  variables:
    stageDeps: $[convertToJson(stageDependencies)]
  jobs:
  - job: LoadEnvVariables
    displayName: "Load Environment Variables Job"
    pool:
      vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
    variables:
      isProduction: $[ stageDependencies.CheckBranch.IdentifyBranch.outputs['VerifyBranchName.isProduction'] ]
      isValidBranch: $[ stageDependencies.CheckBranch.IdentifyBranch.outputs['VerifyBranchName.isValidBranch'] ]
    steps:
      - task: CmdLine@2
        name: LoadEnvironmentValues
        displayName: "Loading values based on branch type"
        inputs:
          script: |
            echo "Checking if it's a production branch..."
            if [ "$(isProduction)" = "true" ]; then
              echo "Production branch detected"
            fi

            echo "Checking if the branch is valid..."
            if [ "$(isValidBranch)" = "true" ]; then
              echo "Valid branch detected: $(isValidBranch)"
            else
              echo "This is not a valid branch, terminating flow."
              exit 1
            fi

            cd aws/greengrass/
            if [ "$(isProduction)" = "true" ]; then
              echo "Loading production environment variables"
              envFile="production.env"
            else
              echo "Loading non-production environment variables"
              envFile="non-production.env"
            fi
  
            # Load environment variables and dynamically create parameters
            while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
              if [[ ! -z "$line" && "$line" != \#* ]]; then
                key=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 1)
                value=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 2-)

                echo "Setting parameter $key=$value"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$key;isOutput=true]$value"
              fi
            done < "$envFile"
      - script: |
          echo "stageDeps - $(stageDeps)"
          echo "COMPONENT_VERSION - $(LoadEnvironmentValues.COMPONENT_VERSION)"
          echo "GW_VERSION is $(LoadEnvironmentValues.GW_VERSION)"
          echo "SSO_ACCOUNT_ID - $(LoadEnvironmentValues.SSO_ACCOUNT_ID)"
          echo "AWS_REGION - $(LoadEnvironmentValues.AWS_REGION)"
          echo "GG_BUCKET_NAME - $(LoadEnvironmentValues.GG_BUCKET_NAME)"
          echo "KINESIS_STREAM - $(LoadEnvironmentValues.KINESIS_STREAM)"
          echo "CORE_DEVICE - $(LoadEnvironmentValues.CORE_DEVICE)"
        displayName: Check output variables

- template: greengrass-component-deployment-templ.yml
  parameters:
    COMPONENT_VERSION: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.COMPONENT_VERSION'] ]
    GW_VERSION: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.GW_VERSION'] ]
    SSO_ACCOUNT_ID: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.SSO_ACCOUNT_ID'] ]
    AWS_REGION: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.AWS_REGION'] ]
    GG_BUCKET_NAME: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.GG_BUCKET_NAME'] ]
    KINESIS_STREAM: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.KINESIS_STREAM'] ]
    CORE_DEVICE: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.CORE_DEVICE'] ]

    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ parameters.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ parameters.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
    AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: ${{ parameters.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN }}

greengrass-component-deployment-templ.yml
parameters:
- name: COMPONENT_VERSION
  default: ''
- name: GW_VERSION
  default: ''
- name: SSO_ACCOUNT_ID
  default: ''
- name: AWS_REGION
  default: ''
- name: GG_BUCKET_NAME
  default: ''
- name: KINESIS_STREAM
  default: ''
- name: CORE_DEVICE
  default: ''

- name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  default: ''
- name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  default: ''
- name: AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
  default: ''

stages:
  - stage: CreateOrUpdateComponent
    dependsOn: LoadEnvironment
    variables:
      stageDeps: $[convertToJson(stageDependencies)]

      COMPONENT_VERSION: ${{ parameters.COMPONENT_VERSION }}
      GW_VERSION: ${{ parameters.GW_VERSION }}
      SSO_ACCOUNT_ID: ${{ parameters.SSO_ACCOUNT_ID }}
      AWS_REGION: ${{ parameters.AWS_REGION }}
      GG_BUCKET_NAME: ${{ parameters.GG_BUCKET_NAME }}
      KINESIS_STREAM: ${{ parameters.KINESIS_STREAM }}
      CORE_DEVICE: ${{ parameters.CORE_DEVICE }}
    displayName: 'Flow for Greengrass Component Creation and Update'
    jobs:
      - job: VerifyS3FolderForGGComponent
        displayName: 'Verify Folder for Greengrass Component'
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
        - script: |
            echo "stageDeps - $(stageDeps)"

            echo "COMPONENT_VERSION - $(COMPONENT_VERSION)"
            echo "GW_VERSION is $(GW_VERSION)"
            echo "SSO_ACCOUNT_ID - $(SSO_ACCOUNT_ID)"
            echo "AWS_REGION - $(AWS_REGION)"
            echo "GG_BUCKET_NAME - $(GG_BUCKET_NAME)"
            echo "KINESIS_STREAM - $(KINESIS_STREAM)"
            echo "CORE_DEVICE - $(CORE_DEVICE)"

            echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID - ${{ parameters.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}"
            echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID - ${{ parameters.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}"
            echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID - ${{ parameters.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN }}"
  



From the current YAML definition indentation, there should be a separate job under the same stage LoadEnvironment as that of the job LoadEnvVariables in greengrass-component-deployment-templ.yml template. We should not use stageDependencies to pass output variables across jobs in the same stage.
Instead, we can use the expression like $[ dependencies.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.COMPONENT_VERSION'] ] according to the document on Levels of output variables. Here is a sample YAML pipeline for your reference.
trigger: none

parameters:
- name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
  default: xxx
- name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  default: yyy
- name: AWS_SESSION_TOKEN 
  default: zzz

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: CheckBranch
  jobs:
  - job: IdentifyBranch
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isProduction;isOutput=true]true"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isValidBranch;isOutput=true]true"
      name: VerifyBranchName
- stage: LoadEnvironment
  displayName: "Load Environment Variables"
  dependsOn: CheckBranch
  variables:
    stageDeps: $[convertToJson(stageDependencies)]
  jobs:
  - job: LoadEnvVariables
    displayName: "Load Environment Variables Job"
    pool:
      vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
    variables:
      isProduction: $[ stageDependencies.CheckBranch.IdentifyBranch.outputs['VerifyBranchName.isProduction'] ]
      isValidBranch: $[ stageDependencies.CheckBranch.IdentifyBranch.outputs['VerifyBranchName.isValidBranch'] ]
    steps:
      - task: CmdLine@2
        name: LoadEnvironmentValues
        displayName: "Loading values based on branch type"
        inputs:
          script: |
            echo "Checking if it's a production branch..."
            if [ "$(isProduction)" = "true" ]; then
              echo "Production branch detected"
            fi

            echo "Checking if the branch is valid..."
            if [ "$(isValidBranch)" = "true" ]; then
              echo "Valid branch detected: $(isValidBranch)"
            else
              echo "This is not a valid branch, terminating flow."
              exit 1
            fi

            cd aws/greengrass/
            if [ "$(isProduction)" = "true" ]; then
              echo "Loading production environment variables"
              envFile="production.env"
            else
              echo "Loading non-production environment variables"
              envFile="non-production.env"
            fi
  
            # Load environment variables and dynamically create parameters
            while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
              if [[ ! -z "$line" && "$line" != \#* ]]; then
                key=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 1)
                value=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 2-)

                echo "Setting parameter $key=$value"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$key;isOutput=true]$value"
              fi
            done < "$envFile"
      - script: |
          echo "stageDeps - $(stageDeps)"
          echo "COMPONENT_VERSION - $(LoadEnvironmentValues.COMPONENT_VERSION)"
          echo "GW_VERSION is $(LoadEnvironmentValues.GW_VERSION)"
          echo "SSO_ACCOUNT_ID - $(LoadEnvironmentValues.SSO_ACCOUNT_ID)"
          echo "AWS_REGION - $(LoadEnvironmentValues.AWS_REGION)"
          echo "GG_BUCKET_NAME - $(LoadEnvironmentValues.GG_BUCKET_NAME)"
          echo "KINESIS_STREAM - $(LoadEnvironmentValues.KINESIS_STREAM)"
          echo "CORE_DEVICE - $(LoadEnvironmentValues.CORE_DEVICE)"
        displayName: Check output variables

  - template: greengrass-component-deployment-templ.yml
    parameters:
      COMPONENT_VERSION: $[ dependencies.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.COMPONENT_VERSION'] ]
      GW_VERSION: $[ dependencies.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.GW_VERSION'] ]
      SSO_ACCOUNT_ID: $[ dependencies.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.SSO_ACCOUNT_ID'] ]
      AWS_REGION: $[ dependencies.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.AWS_REGION'] ]
      GG_BUCKET_NAME: $[ dependencies.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.GG_BUCKET_NAME'] ]
      KINESIS_STREAM: $[ dependencies.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.KINESIS_STREAM'] ]
      CORE_DEVICE: $[ dependencies.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.CORE_DEVICE'] ]

      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ parameters.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ parameters.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: ${{ parameters.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN }}

Sample greengrass-component-deployment-templ.yml
parameters:
- name: COMPONENT_VERSION
  default: ''
- name: GW_VERSION
  default: ''
- name: SSO_ACCOUNT_ID
  default: ''
- name: AWS_REGION
  default: ''
- name: GG_BUCKET_NAME
  default: ''
- name: KINESIS_STREAM
  default: ''
- name: CORE_DEVICE
  default: ''

- name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  default: ''
- name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  default: ''
- name: AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
  default: ''

jobs:
- job: greengrass_component_deployment
  dependsOn: LoadEnvVariables
  variables:
    jobDeps: $[convertToJson(dependencies)]
    COMPONENT_VERSION: ${{ parameters.COMPONENT_VERSION }}
    GW_VERSION: ${{ parameters.GW_VERSION }}
    SSO_ACCOUNT_ID: ${{ parameters.SSO_ACCOUNT_ID }}
    AWS_REGION: ${{ parameters.AWS_REGION }}
    GG_BUCKET_NAME: ${{ parameters.GG_BUCKET_NAME }}
    KINESIS_STREAM: ${{ parameters.KINESIS_STREAM }}
    CORE_DEVICE: ${{ parameters.CORE_DEVICE }}

  steps:
  - script: |
      echo "deps - $(jobDeps)"
      echo "COMPONENT_VERSION - $(COMPONENT_VERSION)"
      echo "GW_VERSION is $(GW_VERSION)"
      echo "SSO_ACCOUNT_ID - $(SSO_ACCOUNT_ID)"
      echo "AWS_REGION - $(AWS_REGION)"
      echo "GG_BUCKET_NAME - $(GG_BUCKET_NAME)"
      echo "KINESIS_STREAM - $(KINESIS_STREAM)"
      echo "CORE_DEVICE - $(CORE_DEVICE)"



Hi @Alvin I have already tried this approach via both dependencies and stageDependencies  it always give error and does not pass value instead it pass same expression
echo "Folder "artifacts/com.test.dl.gs/$[ dependencies.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.COMPONENT_VERSION'] ]" already exists in bucket $[ dependencies.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.GG_BUCKET_NAME'] ]"

/home/vsts/work/_temp/77e789d5-a950-44fb-8be3-8edb0b6b181a.sh: line 1: dependencies.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.AWS_REGION'] : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.AWS_REGION'] ")

Hi @MuhammadMaroof, Did you pass the parameters and defined variables in your template as I did in the answer? Did the subsequent job have the dependsOn: LoadEnvVariables property? Perhaps you may share a minimal YAML context of your template that can reproduce the issue to help understand how you use those template parameters.

Yes I have already these variable declaration but when i put on job level dependOn: LoadEnvVariables, it say unknown depend error while start the job so I move this to stage level and i put my previous stage as dependency. I will share my complete code snipt in few moments.\

Sure. Please share the template context. By the way, your - template has the same indentation as that of the - job: LoadEnvVariables. If you would prefer to output variables across stages, please also share the expectation in the original post, so that I can provide another sample accordingly.Thx.

Hi Alvin I have updated my code in my question so you can have a look

By the way I have change the convertToJson and pass stage level dependencies and I can see output as below : LoadEnvironmentValues.AWS_REGION: eu-central-1,
LoadEnvironmentValues.COMPONENT_VERSION: 1.0.7,
LoadEnvironmentValues.CORE_DEVICE: DevIoTDevice1,
LoadEnvironmentValues.GG_BUCKET_NAME: gg-components-gs-eu-central-1,

deps - {
LoadEnvironment: {
LoadEnvVariables: {
outputs: {
agent.version: 3.243.1,
JobExtension_Init.agent.version: 3.243.1,
JobExtension_Final.agent.version: 3.243.1,
__system_1.agent.version: 3.243.1,
LoadEnvironmentValues.agent.version: 3.243.1,
LoadEnvironmentValues.AWS_REGION: eu-central-1,
}
}
}
}

Hi @MuhammadMaroof, I have updated the answer to reference output variables across stages with the expression AWS_REGION: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs['LoadEnvironmentValues.AWS_REGION'] ]. Since we have defined new variables like AWS_REGION: ${{ parameters.AWS_REGION }} in - stage: CreateOrUpdateComponent to catch the parameters values to be passed into the template, use the macro syntax echo " $(AWS_REGION)" instead of compile time expression echo "${{parameters.AWS_REGION}}". Thx for your sharing and efforts. Wish you a productive week ahead.

Hi @Alvin thanks for your detailed response, I will try this at the moment I have only share single stage  with single job but this stage has multiple  jobs which are doing some task, I tried passing these variable at job level scope of variable was available in the same job / task but in next job I was not able to see values of these variables so in this case I have to again load them at job level and it will create duplication. One more thing is there any side effect of stage to stage level dependencies passing ?

Actually, you may refer to my previous answer if you would output variables across jobs under a single stage. It should work as well if you define variables on downstream job level and reference the variable macro syntax. A stage is a logical boundary in an Azure DevOps pipeline. This document contains several links that may help you explore more on the YAML pipeline key concepts.

Finally after hunting my problem for hours and hours I finally figureout the problem thanks for hints and direction provided by @Alvin, I solve my problem. Only part change in my code is I move these parameter to stage level which were set in previous stage: My template calling is at stage level if you look into my question code.
Just a top level code snipt of my template pipeline.
stages:
  - stage: CreateOrUpdateComponent
    dependsOn: LoadEnvironment
    variables: 
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{parameters.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{parameters.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}
      AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: ${{parameters.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}}
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ${{parameters.AWS_REGION}}
      COMPONENT_VERSION: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs[ 'LoadEnvironmentValues.COMPONENT_VERSION' ] ]
      GW_VERSION: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs[ 'LoadEnvironmentValues.GW_VERSION' ] ]
      SSO_ACCOUNT_ID: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs[ 'LoadEnvironmentValues.SSO_ACCOUNT_ID' ] ]
      AWS_REGION: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs[ 'LoadEnvironmentValues.AWS_REGION' ] ]
      GG_BUCKET_NAME: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs[ 'LoadEnvironmentValues.GG_BUCKET_NAME' ] ]
      KINESIS_STREAM: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs[ 'LoadEnvironmentValues.KINESIS_STREAM' ] ]
      CORE_DEVICE: $[ stageDependencies.LoadEnvironment.LoadEnvVariables.outputs[ 'LoadEnvironmentValues.CORE_DEVICE' ] ]
    displayName: 'Flow for Greengrass Component Creation and Update'
  

Then I update my variable passing reference from ${{parameters.COMPONENT_VERSION}} to $(COMPONENT_VERSION).
Finally i remove the parameters like COMPNENT VERSION etc while calling the template.
 - template: greengrass-component-deployment-templ.yml
    parameters:
       AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ parameters.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
       AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ parameters.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
       AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: ${{ parameters.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN }}

